# The strange power consumption behaviour of a Quadro card when `vfio-pci` has been removed an `nvidial` reattached

Tags: nvidia, kernel-modules, power-management, pci, pci-passthrough

I have built a system with a Geforce GTX 960 and a Quadro M4000 graphics card, that I usually pass through to a virtual machine. The GTX 960 card is only used by the host.

Normally, the Quadro card would not be available by the host, because the kernel driver `vfio-pci` prevents it from being used. However, when I don't use it in the virtual machine, then I would like to have it accessible from the host machine, e.g. to do some computation.

But, there is this very strange behaviour in power consumption and fan speed...
How can I reduce the power consumption and fan speed without needing to have `nvidia-setttings` open all the time?

From my notes:

### Reuse a Passed-through-ready Device on the Host

Supposed a secondary graphics card, that has been prepared for passing it through to a guest, should be used on the host instead.
The device would normally not be usable on the host, since the wrong driver is loaded.
Here, the Quadro M4000 has the `vfio-pci` driver in use, but instead the `nvidia` driver should be used.

```bsh
sudo lspci -nnk | egrep -A3 "VGA|Display|3D"
  # 0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] [10de:1401] (rev a1)
  # Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:36ac]
  # Kernel driver in use: nvidia
  # Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
  # --
  # 0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204GL [Quadro M4000] [10de:13f1] (rev a1)
  # Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1153]
  # Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
  # Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Unload the `vfio-pci` driver and check the device status again.
No kernel driver should be in use, hence line `Kernel driver in use: ...` is gone.

```bsh
sudo modprobe -r vfio-pci
sudo lspci -nnk | egrep -A3 "VGA|Display|3D"
  # 0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] [10de:1401] (rev a1)
  # Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:36ac]
  # Kernel driver in use: nvidia
  # Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
  # --
  # 0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204GL [Quadro M4000] [10de:13f1] (rev a1)
  # Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1153]
  # Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
  # 0c:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fbb] (rev a1)
```

Also check the output of the nvidia driver tool `nvidia-smi`.
It should list only one graphics card (the not-passed-through GTX 960).

```bsh
sudo nvidia-smi 
  # Tue Sep 28 18:19:36 2021       
  # +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  # | NVIDIA-SMI 470.74       Driver Version: 470.74       CUDA Version: 11.4     |
  # |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  # | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
  # | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
  # |                               |                      |               MIG M. |
  # |===============================+======================+======================|
  # |   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:0B:00.0  On |                  N/A |
  # |  0%   51C    P8    19W / 160W |    477MiB /  4040MiB |      0%      Default |
  # |                               |                      |                  N/A |
  # +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  # ...
```

Remove all associated PCI devices from the system.
In this case, those are `0c:00.0` and `0c:00.1`.
Then check that those are actually gone.

```bsh
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:0c\:00.0/remove
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:0c\:00.1/remove
sudo ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/ | grep 0c:00.
  # nothing...
```

Then let it `rescan` for PCI devices and check if the devices are there again and enabled.
Also check which kernel driver is in use and what `nvidia-smi` is telling.

```bsh
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan
sudo ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/ | grep 0c:00.
sudo cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:0c\:00.?/enable
  # 1
  # 1
sudo lspci -nnk | egrep -A3 "VGA|Display|3D"
  # 0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] [10de:1401] (rev a1)
  # Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:36ac]
  # Kernel driver in use: nvidia
  # Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
  # --
  # 0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204GL [Quadro M4000] [10de:13f1] (rev a1)
  # Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1153]
  # Kernel driver in use: nvidia      # <-- here!
  # Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
sudo nvidia-smi 
  # Tue Sep 28 18:26:16 2021       
  # +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  # | NVIDIA-SMI 470.74       Driver Version: 470.74       CUDA Version: 11.4     |
  # |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  # | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
  # | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
  # |                               |                      |               MIG M. |
  # |===============================+======================+======================|
  # |   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:0B:00.0  On |                  N/A |
  # |  0%   47C    P8    19W / 160W |    479MiB /  4040MiB |      0%      Default |
  # |                               |                      |                  N/A |
  # +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  # |   1  Quadro M4000        Off  | 00000000:0C:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
  # | 45%   37C    P0    42W / 120W |      0MiB /  8127MiB |      2%      Default |
  # |                               |                      |                  N/A |
  # +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  # ...
```

Funny enough, the Quadro M4000 consumes about 42 Watts under absolutely no load.
I guess this is due to a driver problem...

**However**, if the graphical `nvidia-settings` program is loaded, the power demand **drops** to about **12 Watts**.

```bsh
# Terminal A
watch -d -n 1 sudo nvidia-smi
# Terminal B
nvidia-settings
```

Watch `nvidia-smi` and listen to the fan noise when the magic happens...

```bsh
watch -d -n 1 sudo nvidia-smi
  # ...
  # +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  # |   1  Quadro M4000        Off  | 00000000:0C:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
  # | 46%   38C    P0    10W / 120W |      0MiB /  8127MiB |      0%      Default |
  # |                               |                      |                  N/A |
  # +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
  # ...
```

Best of all -- `nvidia-settings` does not even list my Quadro card...
[image: No Quadro card in nvidia-settings]